# Strange result of Fuzzywuzzy process extractBests

Tags: python

I have a list of 22 school names and I would like to search for "St. Paul" using process.extractBests. The search result is surprising as there are four elements in the list start with "St Paul", the search returned none of them but something else.

```
>>> schList =["Diocesan Boy's School", "Diocesan Girl's School", 'Heep Yunn School', 'La Salle College', 'Maryknoll Convent School', 'Marymount Secondary School', 'Methodist College', 'Sacred Heart Canossian College', "St Clare's Girl's School", 'St Francis Canossian College', "St Joseph's College", "St Mark's School", "St Mary's Canossian College", "St Paul's Co-educational College", "St Paul's College", "St Paul's Convent School", "St Paul's Secondary School", "St Stephen's Girl's College", 'Wah Yan College, Hong Kong', 'Wah Yan College, Kowloon', 'Ying Wa College', "Ying Wa Girl's School"]
>>> ans= process.extractBests("St. Paul",schList)
>>> ans
[("St Clare's Girl's School", 86), ('St Francis Canossian College', 86), ("St Joseph's College", 86), ("St Mark's School", 86), ("St Mary's Canossian College", 86)]
```

I would like to know if we need any pre-processing for getting a better or more reasonable result?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good to start with what `fuzzywazzy` does. It uses Levenshtein Distance to calculate the differences between sequences. If you loop up what that is you might get this:

> the Levenshtein distance is a string metric for measuring the
> difference between two sequences. Informally, the Levenshtein distance
> between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits
> (insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one word
> into the other.

In other words, your results are the strings that are the easiest to make them look like `St Paul`.

Also, you're saying that you're looking for `St Paul` but in the code you have `St. Paul` with the `.`. That makes a difference.

For example:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

schools = ["Diocesan Boy's School", "Diocesan Girl's School", 'Heep Yunn School', 'La Salle College', 'Maryknoll Convent School', 'Marymount Secondary School', 'Methodist College', 'Sacred Heart Canossian College', "St Clare's Girl's School", 'St Francis Canossian College', "St Joseph's College", "St Mark's School", "St Mary's Canossian College", "St Paul's Co-educational College", "St Paul's College", "St Paul's Convent School", "St Paul's Secondary School", "St Stephen's Girl's College", 'Wah Yan College, Hong Kong', 'Wah Yan College, Kowloon', 'Ying Wa College', "Ying Wa Girl's School"]
print(process.extractBests("St Paul", schools))
```

Gives you this:

```
[("St Paul's Co-educational College", 90), ("St Paul's College", 90), ("St Paul's Convent School", 90), ("St Paul's Secondary School", 90), ("St Clare's Girl's School", 86)]
```

On the other note, if you're looking for strings that contain another string, why not do just this?

```
schools = ["Diocesan Boy's School", "Diocesan Girl's School", 'Heep Yunn School', 'La Salle College', 'Maryknoll Convent School', 'Marymount Secondary School', 'Methodist College', 'Sacred Heart Canossian College', "St Clare's Girl's School", 'St Francis Canossian College', "St Joseph's College", "St Mark's School", "St Mary's Canossian College", "St Paul's Co-educational College", "St Paul's College", "St Paul's Convent School", "St Paul's Secondary School", "St Stephen's Girl's College", 'Wah Yan College, Hong Kong', 'Wah Yan College, Kowloon', 'Ying Wa College', "Ying Wa Girl's School"]
print([s for s in schools if "St Paul" in s])
```

Output: `["St Paul's Co-educational College", "St Paul's College", "St Paul's Convent School", "St Paul's Secondary School"]`

Comment: Thanks baduker for your explanation. I know the case I mentioned can easily be handled by testing the existence of a substring. While FuzzyWuzzy seems capable of solving even more complicated problem, I can't imagine why it provide such seemingly illogical answers. Perhaps the following can better illustrate it. >>> process.extractOne("stpauls S",schList)
("Diocesan Boy's School", 86)